# InvalidFieldNameException using Laravel Doctrine

Tags: php, doctrine-orm, laravel-5, doctrine

I'm converting my Zend Framework 1 app into a Laravel  App. I was using Doctrine so I moved the models to Laravel. I am using [laravel-doctrine](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/)

The fields are written in camelCase and when the database was created through doctrine, they were also created in camelCase, like this:

```
/**
 * @ORM\Entity (repositoryClass="Repositories\Customer")
 * @ORM\Table(name="customers")
 * @ORM\HasLifecycleCallbacks
 */
class Customer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\Id @ORM\Column(type="integer")
     * @ORM\GeneratedValue(strategy="AUTO")
     */
    private $id;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $firstName;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $lastName;

    /** @ORM\Column(type="string", length=255, nullable=true) */
    protected $companyName;
```

When I do  `EntityManager::find('App\Entities\Customer', 1);` I get this error:

> An exception occurred while executing 'SELECT t0.id AS id_1,
>   t0.firstName AS firstName_2, t0.lastName AS lastName_3,
>   t0.company_name AS company_name_4, t0.email AS email_5,
>   t0.phone_number AS phone_number_6, t0.type AS type_7, t0.created AS
>   created_8, t0.updated AS updated_9, t0.jobsource_id AS jobsource_id_10
>   FROM customers t0 WHERE t0.id = ?' with params [1](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/): SQLSTATE[42S22]:
>   Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 't0.company_name' in 'field
>   list'

Is there a reason why is looking for underscore? Is there a way for me to change that?

I am using PHP 7.0.1

Answer (score 4, accepted):

laraveldoctrine.org supports defining custom naming strategies:

Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultNamingStrategy Is probably the one you are looking for.

In doctrine.php config file: (after you have published it to your project)

```
'managers'                  => [
        'default' => [
            'naming_strategy' => 'Doctrine\ORM\Mapping\DefaultNamingStrategy',
            'dev'        => env('APP_DEBUG'),
            'meta'       => env('DOCTRINE_METADATA', 'annotations'),
            'connection' => env('DB_CONNECTION', 'mysql'),
            'paths'      => [
                base_path('app')
            ],
           ....
      ]
]
```

If you want a custom one, implement the naming strategy according to: http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html

Comment: Who downvoted this? I wrote the package, why would I give an invalid answer?

Comment: I did. The original question didn't state that raygo was using laravel-doctrine. So answering the question assuming another framework was the reason. I've removed the downvote now that question fits the correct answer. Hope you understand.

Comment: The moment I answered the question, the link to laravel-doctrine was already in his question.

Answer (score 0):

[Snake case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Snake_case) is the default style for column names for many frameworks. You can specify the table column name by your property:

```
/** @Column(type="string", length=255, name="companyName", nullable=true) */
private $companyName;
```

You can change the overall naming strategy, [see the docs for that](http://doctrine-orm.readthedocs.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/namingstrategy.html). Laravel doesn't support it out of the box, but it is relatively few changes needed to [make it work](https://github.com/Supericy/laravel-doctrine/commit/8b351f7c1878fea4a03c381344ecb37fbb6dd7f2).
If you don't want to mess with your Laravel code there is also the [drop-in replacement for Doctrine](http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/) that has this feature and many more built-in.

Comment: Since I am migrating the models, I have many fields that I would need to do that to. Wondering if there's an easier way so I won't have to add extra annotations to all my models. Thanks

Comment: I saw that url, but that configuration is different from laravel-doctrine

Comment: You should be able to change it to camel-case

Comment: There is a pull request for that. It is relatively few changes: https://github.com/Supericy/laravel-doctrine/commit/8b351f7c1878fea4a03c381344ecb37fbb6dd7f2

Comment: It is from 2014, but the it seems like it is going to be merged with Laravel now.

Comment: There is also this http://www.laraveldoctrine.org/ if you don't want to mess with your Laravel code

Comment: Yes, I'm trying laraveldoctrine.org so I cant use the solution from Supericy/laravel-doctrine

Comment: @raygo well you only need to use one of them so that's fine :)